# Mixing an IF-statement in an UPDATE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm working on a SQL Server 2008 database. This database has two tables.

```
Book
ID
BookCategoryID
Name
IsFlagged

BookCategory
ID
Name
IsFlagged
```

I need to update the BookCategory table so that if any books in a category are flagged, the IsFlagged property on the BookCategory record is set to true. Otherwise, if there are not any books in a category that are flagged, I need to set the IsFlagged property on the BookCategory record to false. Is there a way to do this? I can't seem to figure it out. I was trying something like the following but kept hitting a dead-end.

```
UPDATE
  BookCategory
SET
  IsFlagged = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Book WHERE [IsFlagged]=1 AND [BookCategory]=?)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE bc
SET IsFlagged = CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM
    BookCategory bc LEFT JOIN
    Book b ON b.BookCategoryID = bc.ID AND b.IsFlagged = 1
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this update each BookCategory record once or would it update once for every flagged Book in the category? IE updating the same BookCategory multiple times

Comment: You probably should indicate this is SQL Server-specific syntax.  I don't think other RDBMS support `UPDATE...FROM` but I'm not positive.

Comment: @JNK You're right, I don't think other RBDMS support it... but the OP specified SQL Server in the question...

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson didn't notice!  I just noticed the tags which were generic.  Thanks for fixing that.  +1

Comment: @msmucker0527 Good question.  From MSDN: ["a single `UPDATE` statment never updates the same row two times."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE BookCategory
SET IsFlagged = 0

UPDATE BookCategory b
SET IsFlagged = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Books
              WHERE bookCategoryid = b.id
              AND isFlagged = 1)
```